# how to use karate.match in javascript

Tags: karate

given the following scenario:

```
 Scenario: check if the array contains a string

  * def condition = 
  """
  function(){ 
  var myFile = "computer3.jpg"
  var getAttachment = ["computer3.jpg"]
  var isFound = karate.match(getAttachment + " contains " + myFile)
  karate.log("is Found", isFound)
  return isFound.pass
  }
  """
  * def r = call condition
```

I have the following error:

```
ReferenceError: "computer3" is not defined
```

How can I check if an array contains some values inside javascript using karate.match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution worked for me

```
Scenario: prova 2

  * def condition = 
  """
  function(){ 
  var myFile = "computer3.jpg"
  var getAttachment = ["computer3.jpg"]
  var temp = "['" + getAttachment+ "'] contains '" + myFile+"'"
  var isFound = karate.match(temp)

  karate.log("is Found:", isFound)
  return isFound.pass
  }
  """
  * def r = call condition
```